# How do I get return to print to console in this code?

Tags: python

```
def distance_from_zero(distance):
    if type(distance) == int or type(distance) == float:
        return abs(distance)
        print(distance)
    else:
        return "Nope"
        print distance_from_zero(distance)

distance_from_zero(18)
```

Comment: any code after a return is not executed! keep that in mind when programming

Comment: At the moment, putting the `return` statement before the recursive call is the only thing preventing infinite recursion in that case.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by "get return to print". My best guess is "print the returned value" - ?

Answer (score 2):

You should print before returning. Once you return, your print statement is not reachable.

replace:

```
return abs(distance)
print(distance)
```

with:

```
print(distance)
return abs(distance)
```

And this:

```
return "Nope"
print distance_from_zero(distance)
```

with:

```
print distance_from_zero(distance)
return "Nope"
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I have another quick question. In the console there is always a none at the end of my code. Why is that?

Comment: @JacobKJakielaszek Can you copy paste the entire thing you wrote in console along with the output in console?

Answer (score 0):

The code after return will never be executed.

You have to revert the order.

Something like:

```
print(distance)
return abs(distance)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the original code with the print statements put in the correct place. Note the infinite recursion error that still shows up.

```
def distance_from_zero(distance):
    if type(distance) == int or type(distance) == float:
        print(distance)
        return abs(distance)
    else:
        # This print forces infinite recursion because of distance
        # print distance_from_zero(distance)
        return "Nope"
```

This is a way of testing it

```
def distance_from_zero(distance):
    if type(distance) == int or type(distance) == float:
        print(distance)
        return abs(distance)
    else:
        try:
            distance = float(distance)
            print(distance)
            return abs(distance)
        except:
            print ("invalid distance specified", distance)
            return "Nope"
```

Of course, the initial if can be dropped since `float(int)` and `float(float)` still return a normal float.

```
def distance_from_zero(distance):
    try:
        distance = float(distance)
        print(distance)
        return abs(distance)
    except:
        print ("invalid distance specified", distance)
        return "Nope"
```

Comment: It looks like you left out the equals sign between `distance` and `float(distance)`

Comment: @zondo Thanks. I will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why do you need to check the type of the argument before calling `abs()`?. Just call it. `abs()` knows best the types of operands that it can work with. If it sees one that it can't handle a `TypeError` exception will be raised and the caller can deal with it.

If you really want to handle the error in your function, use a `try/except` block instead of trying to guess the types that `abs()` supports, e.g. complex numbers are supported; `abs(complex(1, 2))` is perfectly valid:

```
try:
    distance = abs(distance)
except TypeError as e:
    print('{!r} is not a valid distance'.format(distance))
    return None    # or some other error
else:
    print(distance)
    return distance
```

Finally, if you really do want to limit support to only `int` and `float` types, it is better to use `isinstance()` than `type()` because is supports inheritance:

```
if isinstance(distance, (int, float)):
    # it's a float or an int
    distance = abs(distance)
```

A couple of other things to note:

- Call `print()` before calling `return` in the function. `return`
  terminates the function and returns execution to the calling code, so any statements after the `return` will not be executed.
- You seem to want to print the value of distance *after* `abs()`, so
  you need to store the result in a variable (or perform the calculation twice):

  ```
  distance = abs(distance)
  print(distance)
  return distance
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Python stops reading the definition after you've `return`ed something, so you should swap the `print` and `return` commands around.